# Showing hyperlinks to external websites in Django (with Sites Framework). Sites Model is putting a text prefix

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am running into some problem with Django hyperlinks on a template page due to a usage of Sites framework. Tried many options but they are not working.

---

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Surname", max_length=60)
    facebook = models.URLField(max_length=400, blank=True, default='https://www.fb.com')

class SiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
fields = ('id', 'name', 'domain')
```

---

In the database name=n/a, domain = booksite for the site model

In the template, called the link using absolutize module (https://pypi.org/project/django-absoluteuri/) as below

```
<div class='icon social fb' ><a class=' fa fa-facebook' title="click to view facebook profile" style="color:white;"
                                href="{{ object.facebook|absolutize }}" ></a></div>
```

---

however, the hyperlink is rendering as n/ahttps://www.fb.com. The n/a is being picked up from the site's model. Maybe this is a very simple thing but am not able to figure out. Can someone please point out, how to get rid of the n/a prefix in the hyperlink?
I tried deleting the row in the site's model but the app is not working without at-least one data point in the site's model.
Greatly appreciate any help from the community.

Comment: try removing `|absolutize`.

Comment: Hi Raydel, my sincere apologies for not mentioning that by not having absolutize, the template is rendering the URL field with http://127.0.0.1:8000:https://www.facebook.com   I was looking to have it just render the absolute hyperlink (:https://www.facebook.com)

Comment: Hi Ramani, I've tried but I can't reproduce your situation. Please look into the database and you will see the url is saved correctly.

Comment: Thank you Raydel. your answer worked. just removing absolutize worked it all out. Silly me. Don't know what caused the error in first place.